# Check several files with MD5

Tags: md5sum

Every month, a company sends me a hard drive - ext4 encrypted with cryptsetup -  with backup files from a server. In that drive there are 1000+ files, and they almost fill up a 2Tb HDD. Each file has a corresponding .md5 file so we can check the integrity of it, but as you could imagine, I can't check every single one of them by hand in terminal, so I copy them to another hard drive and check them in Windows. On Ubuntu is there any way to check all files, or even just all files in a folder? Thanks.

Comment: @xdevs23 Well, I moved some folders to  the local drive, changed permissions and ran the script. In under 2 secs it told me everything was OK but it seemed weird that it would complete so quickly. I modified a file just so it would not match, but it told me everything was ok. (sorry for the delay btw)

Comment: I am sorry for you mate, seems to be that the script contains an error, I tried to fix it but it didn't work so far, maybe I will get a solution later.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can.
Assuming every file has just a md5 file in the same directory with just a appending `.md5`, create a script file (e. g. `md5check.sh`) with following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Building file list..."
$ALLFLS="$(find)"
echo "Checking all files..."
for word in $ALLFLS; do
    if [[ $(cat "$word.md5") == $(md5sum -b "$word") ]]; then
        echo "$word OK"
    else
        echo "MD5 wrong for $word"
        exit
    fi
done
echo "All files correct!"
```

This checks if every file. Please report if it worked. (Make sure you have changed the directory to your hard drive before executing the script and make sure you have `chmod +x` it)

Edit:

You can also check [this page](http://info.michael-simons.eu/2008/10/25/recursively-md5sum-all-files-in-a-directory-tree/).

Answer (score 3):

This information is weirdly hard to find, but if you want to check all the md5's against their respective files in a directory (for example Downloads) you just:

```bsh
cd Downloads
md5sum -c *.md5
```

This will output a list of the files checked with either OK or FAILED

See: https://linux.die.net/man/1/md5sum for more information.

Comment: Note that this does not work if the shell expands the wildcard and the file list is too long

Answer (score 0):

If all the files are in the same directory (no subdirectories), you can run `md5sum -c` on every `.md5` file. The following will also save errors to a file which you can check afterwards.

```sh
logerrors="md5errors.log"
for f in *.md5; do
    md5sum -c "$f" 2>> "$logerrors" || echo "ERROR on $f"
done
```

If your .md5 files are also to be found in subdirectories, you can use something like this:

```sh
find . -type f -name "*.md5" \
| while read f; do
    d="$(dirname "$f")"; b="$(basename "$f")"
    ( cd "$d"; md5sum -c "$b" || echo "Error on $f" | tee -a "$logerrors" )
  done
```

See also `man md5sum`. In particular, you may want to use the `--quiet` option:

> don't print OK for each successfully verified file